# Rendering Error after adding another dependencies

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDlA.png) after making a toggle for password visibility.
I added the following in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

I can't seem to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: What is your problem? Explain more on that

Comment: Just change the API level to 23 or less in the layout preview

Comment: post your gradle error.

Comment: I cant upload a photo to show what the error was =(

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDlA.png  check it out

Comment: what is the build tool version you are using.